# How would you translate "Kommandostab", "command bar", from German?

Tags: word-choice, translation, military, image-identification

How would you translate "Kommandostab" from German? The literate translation is "command bar", this object was used to give orders to the army. Full sentence: "In der rechten Hand hält er einen Kommandostab, in der Linken die Zügel." It appears on the third page (page 6) of [this German periodical](http://archiv.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/artdok/2466/1/Bechter_Der_Goldene_Reiter_ein_Wahrzeichen_Dresdens_2004.pdf).

[image: goldene reiter model]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is typically known as a ***baton*** in English (we imported the word from French).

From Wikipedia's article on the [martial *baton*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baton_(symbol)):

> The ceremonial *baton* is a short, thick stick-like object, typically in wood or metal, that is traditionally the sign of a field marshal or a similar very high-ranking military officer, and carried as a piece of their uniform.
>
> [image: Jean-Baptiste Jourdan with a marshall!s baton]

Related, of course, but distinct, is the royal *[scepter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sceptre)*.